# How to pass javascript Buffer to C program or NAPI?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, pointers

I have JavaScript in which i have created a **buffer** . i am reading file and storing file data in the buffer.i have to pass buffer data to NAPI/ c program. I have created node module . for using JavaScript buffer in the c program/ NAPI i need *uint8_t .
I have tried to use **napi_get_buffer_info** function for getting Javascript buffer details and data .
I am able to get length of the JavaScript buffer pass to the NAPI/ c program.
Sample code
**nodejstest.js**

```
var addon = require('bindings')('test');
const fs = require('fs');

const BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
var buffer = new Buffer.alloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
var ps_uploadPathLocal = 'sampletext.txt';
var fileHandle = fs.openSync(ps_uploadPathLocal, "rs");
var bytesRead = fs.readSync(fileHandle, buffer, 0, 50, 0);
console.log("\nPrinting Buffer value ");
console.log(buffer);
console.log("\nBuffer to String");
console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));
console.log("Bytes Read from the string ",bytesRead);
console.log(addon.upload(buffer));  // 'world'
```

**test.cc**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <node_api.h>
#include <stdio.h>

napi_value uploadfunc(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
  napi_status status;
  napi_value world;

  size_t argc = 1;
  napi_value args[1];
  status = napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, nullptr, nullptr);
  assert(status == napi_ok);

  if (argc < 1) {
    napi_throw_type_error(env, nullptr, "Wrong number of arguments");
    return nullptr;
  }

  napi_valuetype valuetype0;
  status = napi_typeof(env, args[0], &valuetype0);
  assert(status == napi_ok);

  printf("Value type of the buffer %d \n", valuetype0);

  bool buffertype;
  status = napi_is_buffer(env, args[0], &buffertype);
  assert(status == napi_ok);
  printf("If Buffer type %d \n",buffertype);


  //napi_is_arraybuffer
  bool buffertype1;
  status = napi_is_arraybuffer(env, args[0], &buffertype1);
  assert(status == napi_ok);
  printf("If Buffer type %d \n",buffertype1);

  //napi_get_buffer_info
  size_t lengthOfBuffer;
  dataptr = &data;
  void* clsData;
  status = napi_get_buffer_info(env, args[0], &clsData,&lengthOfBuffer);
  assert(status == napi_ok);

  printf("Length of the buffer in C program %zd \n", lengthOfBuffer);

  status = napi_create_string_utf8(env, "upload", 5, &world);
  assert(status == napi_ok);
  return world;
}

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func)                                        \
  { name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0 }

napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
  napi_status status;
  napi_property_descriptor uploadv = DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("upload", uploadfunc);
  status = napi_define_properties(env, exports, 1, &uploadv);
  assert(status == napi_ok);

  return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

Question:
1) How can i get pointer(*uint8_t) of the Javascript buffer and pass to c function ?
2) How can i print JavaScript buffer data in c program ?

Comment: I guess the Javascript buffer is just a simple pointer and need the length to avoid Segmentation Fault. I'm gonna play with buffer and NAPI soon too. Please answer if you found out how to do.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP first i have created a null pointer and then passed this pointer to napi_get_buffer_info function and then convert void type pointer to unit_8 type pointer.

void* ptrtobuffer = NULL; 
uint8_t *ptrtodata ; 
ptrtodata = (uint8_t *)ptrtobuffer;